# MVP. Where to store presenter`s cache when activity is recreating?

Tags: android, android-activity, mvp

I`m try to refactor my app with MVP pattern and also whant to replace fragments with views in the future.

How can i store presenter`s cached data when activity configuration is changing? I don't want to use SQLite, shared preferences, static fields, singletones, retaining fragments. What i want is to store and kill cache properly according to Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found soulution for this.

http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/mvp-presenters-that-survive-configuration-changes-part-2/

That guy keep every presenter in some kind of PresenterCacheManager and then store that cache view Activity's `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` method and restore it with `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance`.

That is what i looking for yaaay.